# getting image from gallery but large greater then 3 mb image is not loaded in imageview

Tags: android, xampp

> the small images are loaded successully but the large images e,g greater then 3mb are not loaded in image view. i am also capturing image from camera it is working fine,but from gallery it is not loaded in the image view and it remain empty.i do not know how to fix that issue

```
 public void gallery() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, PHOTO_FROM_MEMORY_REQUESTED);
}
 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode== REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        try {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                iv.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                image = encode(imageBitmap);//this line is added to encode
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){ Toast.makeText(DoReport.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    }
    else if (requestCode == PHOTO_FROM_MEMORY_REQUESTED && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        updateSelectedPicture(data.getData());
    }

}
 private void updateSelectedPicture(Uri uri){
    try{
        imageUri = uri;
        InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        iv.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(selectedImage));
        image=encode(selectedImage);

    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){

        Log.e("File not found", "Cannot find background file under received URI");
    }
}
public static String encode(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;
}
```

//here is xml code

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="197dp"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/ImgView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you can not just use the image from gallary or camera as it is. You have to compress this image before doing any operation (**3mb is a large data and now mobiles have 5mb> image also**).

- You will compress the image after getting its URI.

For that [enter link description here](http://Image%20compressor) has done great work. You will just use easy methods of this library.

Add this to app level `Build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
}
```

and easy method

**Compress Image File**

```
compressedImageFile = new Compressor(this).compressToFile(actualImageFile);
```

**Compress Image File to Bitmap**

```
compressedImageBitmap = new Compressor(this).compressToBitmap(actualImageFile);
```

See in below image, this image compressing method compress your image in a great manner. Which looks still same with large difference in size.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<application android:largeHeap="true"</application>` and I am also suggest [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for dealing with images.

Answer (score -1):

Remember, that you your app has a heap limitation, which is different on different devices. To reduce size of image, you can compress it:

```
Bitmap original; // the original bitmap you want to compress
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, VALUE, out);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

Where the `VALUE` is an integer from 0 to 100. 0 represents the max compression (the minimum quality).

Comment: kindly can you tell me where to add these line in my code.

Comment: Firstly, u should extact it to separate method, e.g. private Bitmap compressImage(Bitmap b);

And then use it when u got bitmap from bundle or from input stream.

Comment: private void  compressImage(Bitmap b)
   {
            Bitmap original; // the original bitmap you want to compress
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, out);
            Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
            iv.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(decoded));
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }